# SimpleDateFormat with Timezone names in different languages

Tags: android, date, locale, timestamp-with-timezone

I have encountered this strange problem when trying to parse date strings, which I have nailed down to this:

Device with some English locale (the emulator):

`Date.toString()` gives "Thu Feb 18 13:25:22 GMT 2016"

```
DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
d1 = newDateFormat.parse("Thu Feb 18 13:25:22 GMT 2016"); //works fine
```

Device with German locale:

`Date.toString()` gives "Thu Feb 18 13:25:22 MEZ 2016" (note the timezone in German, while Thursday is still Thursday)

```
DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
d1 = newDateFormat.parse("Thu Feb 18 13:25:22 MEZ 2016"); //does not parse

DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
d1 = newDateFormat.parse("Thu Feb 18 13:25:22 MEZ 2016"); //does not parse

DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
String s = "Thu Feb 18 13:25:22 MEZ 2016";
s.replace("MEZ", "CET");
d1 = newDateFormat.parse(s); //works fine, but doesn't seem very portable
```

So I am looking for a way to either get SimpleDateFormat to ignore the time zone completely (that would be fine for my app, the only thing I am trying to do here is give a time difference to "last time", which will be given in hours if it's less than a day, but in days or weeks if it's more, so the time zone won't matter that much for this use case),

or for a way to get `SimpleDateFormat` to understand timezones in the device language.

Bonus points for a good way to save the date in a language-independent way, while still retaining information such as timezone and time of day in that time zone. (for when I upgrade my database next time)

Comment: "Bonus points for a good way to save the date in a language-independent way, while still retaining information such as timezone and time of day in that time zone" iso8601 datetime format is your answer

Comment: In the string `String s = "Thu Feb 18 13:25:22 MEZ 2016";` why are you replacing `MEZ` with `CET` , why are you changing the time zone of that time? This is wrong, as that time stamp is for MEZ time zone and you are just replacing that to CET timezone

Comment: MEZ and CET are the same thing, just in two different languages

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out how to persist any given Date object with timezone, or do you actually have to parse these strings with date/time components from different locales?

Comment: Well, due to poor design choices when starting to write the app, these strings were in my database. Now I know of course that it would have been a much better idea to save them in some nicer format, for example +0100 or something, but to change it in my database I have to figure out how to properly parse them (or brute force string replace all time zone strings that could possibly have ended up in the database... which is what I actually did in the end, but I thought I'd keep the question around for people with the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way to get the current date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String CurrentDate = formatter.format(new Date());
Date current_date = formatter.parse(CurrentDate); //In case need the entire Date value
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not really, I asked specifically about keeping the time zone information. And anyway, the date strings are what they are now, I can't change them (at least not easily)

Comment: So you want to convert Date strings from German Locale to US, right? Correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: @fifaltra -- Please see my edited section once. I have added the line `formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`. Let me know if this is fine for you.

Comment: I want to parse date strings with 3 letters containing the timezone, where the 3 letter string is in the locale of the device.

Comment: With the updated code you will get UTC Dates based on the device Locale.

Comment: But I already have the Date strings, they are not changeable. This is NOT about making new Date strings with a nice format, I should have done that but I didn't, so now I'm stuck with the annoying format.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired result (which i believe looks something like: **Mi. März 15:15:58 02-03-16 MEZ**)

I used to the following code:

```js
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yy z";
private DateTimeFormatter mDateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT).withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

/**
 * Get formatted Date as Human Readable String
 * @param dateTime the time to print
 * @return Date as String
 */
public String getFormattedDate(@NonNull DateTime dateTime) {
    return mDateFormatter.print(dateTime);
}
```

If you want a Time difference, you might wanna take look at `JodaTime` (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). I've used it myself, it provides simple interfaces for time differences (`Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Months`, `Seconds`, `Weeks`, `Years`).

Save your Dates in Unix Time (ISO 8601), its all the information you need.

Comment: Calculating the time difference is not my problem, parsing the Date string is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you are instantiating SimpleDateFormat,

`DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");`

`SimpleDateFormat` has a constructor that takes in a locale, `SimpleDateFormat(String)` constructor has been deprecated now, you should use the constructor that takes in the locale too like so,

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Now if you use this `df.parse(myDateString)` you don't need to do string replace from `MEZ` to `CET` because the SimpleDateFormat knows your locale will parse the date properly

Comment: I thought so too, but `Locale.getDefault()` also didn't work for some reason

Comment: @fifaltra `Locale.getDefault()` returns the default locale of the device, if your test device has default Locale of US, then ofcourse Time stamps with locale Germany wont work ! Try changing the locale of your device before testing timestamps of different locale

Comment: obviously I tried the Germany locale on a German device, to try to force it to German locale, because getDefault also didn't work.

Comment: but thats how android specifies how you are supposed to use the date api there no other way of finding out which locale the device is in